# Mysql connector/C++ for windows 2010 express not compiling

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

SOLUTION: I have decided to make a step by step guide for people having the same issues.  I don't know if this fully fixes everything but it does let you compile the code snippet I will provide.  If there are any errors please comment so I can fix them.  This is intended to help those who have mostly given up from failed attempts, and to be frank, the whole process should have been documented.  Sorry for the long post :P

```
STEP BY STEP FOR SETTING UP MYSQL CONNECTOR/C++ FOR 2010 MICROSOFT VISUAL C++ EXPRESS:
FILES NEEDED:
Windows x86 32 Bit ZIP: Connector/C++ -> http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/
Windows X86 32 Bit ZIP: Connector/C -> http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/
BOOST -> http://www.boost.org/users/download/

The reason why 62bit doesn't work is because you are using the express edition.  After you have downloaded all those files, extract them.  I keep mine in C (for ease of access).  Now open up MVC++ 2010 EXPRESS.
File -> New -> Project
Win32 Console Application
Next
Check Empty project
Finish
Create your first .cpp.  I call mine main.cpp
Project -> Properties
C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> C:\mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.0-win32\mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.0-win32\include
C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> C:\mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.0-win32\mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.0-win32\include\cppconn
C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> C:\boost_1_49_0
Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> C:\mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.0-win32\mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.0-win32\lib
Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> C:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32\lib
The reason why we downloaded the Connector/C is because it has two files we need: libmysql.lib and libmysql.dll
Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> mysqlcppconn.lib
Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> libmysql.lib

If you change to Release, youll have to enter in the information again.
In your main.cpp place the following code and build it:
```

=

```
/* Copyright 2008, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.

There are special exceptions to the terms and conditions of the GPL
as it is applied to this software. View the full text of the
exception in file EXCEPTIONS-CONNECTOR-C++ in the directory of this
software distribution.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA
*/

/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;



int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' » AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "YOUR USERNAME", "YOUR PASSWORD");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("YOUR DATABASE");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line »" << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

int a;      // hangs
cin >> a;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You should get errors for int8_t.  Double click the config.h located at: c:\mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.0-win32\mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.0-win32\include\cppconn\config.h.  Double click it to bring it up.  Now just comment out all the typedefs there should only be 8.  Place the libmysql.dll(inside the Connector/C) and mysqlcppconn.dll(inside the Connector/C++) inside the folder the compiler is outputting your build to. When finished save and run.

**OLD POSTS DONT LOOK**

I have followed the steps on this site verbatim: http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/?p=215
But I am still getting a compile error.  I'm not new to linking libraries, or including directories, but I could use a new super-hero who has made applications with mysql connector/c++ with 2010 express... to make a simple KISS example.  I have been grinding my teeth all day.
Example Source: http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/07/mysql-connector-c-example-windows-clexe.html (with changed database)

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__get_driver_instance referenced in function _main

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

int main(){

    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;

    try{
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
        con->setSchema("foxlogin");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        stmt->execute("insert into example values(4,'four'),(5, 'five')");
        delete stmt;

        pstmt = con->prepareStatement("select * from example");
        res = pstmt->executeQuery();
        while (res->next())
            std::cout<<res->getInt("id")<<"  "<<res->getString("data")<<std::endl;
        delete res;
        delete pstmt;

        pstmt = con->prepareStatement("delete from example where id=?");
        pstmt->setInt(1,4);
        pstmt->executeUpdate();
        pstmt->setInt(1,5);
        pstmt->executeUpdate();

        delete pstmt;

        delete con;    
    }catch(sql::SQLException &e){
        std::cout<<e.what();
    }

    int a;      // hang
    cin >> a;

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: I have followed this also: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,492097,492097#msg-492097 I even used the C++, and C connectors (separate builds) along with BOTH tests with each 64, and 32 bit versions (a total of 4 tests).  I have downloaded boost and linked it.  The new code I am using I will post below which comes from the official mysql website.  Both builds produce the SAME errors.

```
/* Copyright 2008, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.

There are special exceptions to the terms and conditions of the GPL
as it is applied to this software. View the full text of the
exception in file EXCEPTIONS-CONNECTOR-C++ in the directory of this
software distribution.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA
*/

/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' » AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

BUILD ERRORS FOR 64 TEST: (I dint include the 32bit build error test, if you need Ill provide)

```
   1>------ Build started: Project: erthwrthj, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>  main.cpp
    1>c:\mysql c++ 64\include\cppconn\sqlstring.h(36): warning C4251: 'sql::SQLString::realStr' : class 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::SQLString'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Elem=char,
    1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
    1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
    1>          ]
    1>c:\mysql c++ 64\include\mysql_connection.h(156): warning C4251: 'sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection::proxy' : class 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              T=sql::mysql::NativeAPI::NativeConnectionWrapper
    1>          ]
    1>c:\mysql c++ 64\include\cppconn\exception.h(59): warning C4251: 'sql::SQLException::sql_state' : class 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::SQLException'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Elem=char,
    1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
    1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
    1>          ]
    1>c:\mysql c++ 64\include\cppconn\config.h(60): error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(17) : see declaration of 'int8_t'
    1>c:\mysql c++ 64\include\cppconn\config.h(60): error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(17) : see declaration of 'int8_t'
    1>c:\users\null\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\erthwrthj\erthwrthj\main.cpp(74): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '»'
    1>c:\users\null\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\erthwrthj\erthwrthj\main.cpp(74): error C2065: '»' : undeclared identifier
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Help would be appreciated!

UPDATE 2:  view_findpost_*p*_1474626">http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/253647-question-regarding-connecting-to-mysql-50-using-visual-studio-2010/page_*view*_findpost_*p*_1474626 This guy seems to think it is because config.h conflicts with stdint.h on compile because in config.h there is a #typedef for int8_t.  There has to be a solution to this.  Ill even take any other libraries(free) that can connect to a local MySQL database, but I am really eager to figure this out to help everyone out.

Comment: Did you try to add an additional library dependency to libmysql.lib? You can download it from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Comment: Yes.  This is my second venture trying to get it working.  And the second time I have lost.

Comment: `The reason why 62bit doesn't work` Was that really a copy & paste from the output? I wouldn't be surprised that someone at Microsoft wrote such an incorrect statement, but I was wondering... Why is your QUESTION starting with "SOLUTION"? If you had a working answer, then you should write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is plenty of questions about C++ and MySQL connector, and it is really hard to make it working, I'll answer this question even this was asked like 1 year ago.

Solution is pretty easy, only thing you need to do is to comment all typedef's in cppcon/config.h file