# Linking error in connecting mysql with C++ VS2010

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, mysql-connector

```
//#include <mysql.h>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "libmysql.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mysqlcppconn.lib")
```

Above are my libraries , i follow the step for configuration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241465/mysql-connector-c-for-windows-2010-express-not-compiling)

here is my error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add project  "Library Directory" for mysqlcppconn.lib
see here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee855621.aspx

Comment: 1)try to find you lib file (on my pc C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5\lib\opt" 2)Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories and add this folder )