# Connecting VS Express 2013 to MySQL with Connector C++ 1.1.3 - error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2013

> **Scroll down for (part of) the solution that I found:**

I'm on a **Windows 8.1, 64 bit laptop**
It is my first time trying to connect C++ to MySQL using the mentioned connector.
The error is as follow:

```
   Error 1  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(void)" (?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Profile\Profile\Profile.obj Profile
```

This is my main code:

```
// Profile.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

#define dbHOST "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306"
#define dbUSER "root"
#define dbPASS "root"
#define dbDB   "db_test"

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

int main()
{

    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect(dbHOST, dbUSER, dbPASS);

    delete con;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have followed the instructions from [this mysql site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html) for the static installation.

I have also Google quite a lot with the error.
Some suggested it could be the connector files different for 64bit and 32bits - I've tried downloading both (they are installed in Program Files and Program Files (x86) accorindgly. but the error persists.

One thing to note, when I link it with the 32bit connector files, it will have a huge load more of errors.

Makes me wonder after all the search, is it that VS Express 2013 is not compatible to connect with MySQL thus far?
I heard ppl saying using the Qt would be easier, but I still want to try this out.

Please let me know if my question is vague or if you need more information.
Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION I FOUND**
I don't want to add it as an answer because it does not remedy the question I asked.
Anyway, I found a [link which gives fairly simple instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241465/mysql-connector-c-for-windows-2010-express-not-compiling) which has got it to work. Would still appreciate if anyone is willing to look into my original issue.
:)

Comment: Steps 11 and 12 in the linked page. Did you follow them?

Comment: Yes I did. However, as it says

`Add the lib/opt directory into the Additional Library Directories text field. This enables the library file libmysql.lib to be found.`

The libmysql.lib is no where to be found in the lib\opt folder, so instead, I included it from a MySQL Server 5.6\lib folder, since there's one there.

Is this wrong?

Comment: I would say so, but not 100% sure.

Comment: I did a search online about missing libmysql.lib and there were no direct solutions. One said was to copy it and paste it in the lib\opt folder, I did, then I double checked the linked path. Still the same error. || Another thing I did was to move the mySQL files out of Program Files cause I thought it might affect, but it still shows the same error. :(